# Php on windows and blocks

Tags: php, windows

My development PC has windows installed. And I've experienced weird php behaviour:

```
<?php

file_put_contents('c:/q', microtime(1) . "\r\n", FILE_APPEND);

sleep(10);
```

When I run this script in browser simultaneously in two different tabs I get such results

```
1294713622.125
1294713632.2188
```

which obviously is not what I expected, although in CLI everything is fine.

So the question: what can block execution? (`session.auto_start` is `Off`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is in Firefox. It doesn't run requests simultaneously if the requests headers are identical. The issue disappears if `network.http.use-cache` is disabled in Firefox's config.

it's a good idea to report this bug to mozilla ;)

Comment: Since this is the person who answered this question personally in jabber, I check this answer.

Answer (score 0):

microtime() returns the current UNIX timestamp in microseconds. You should expect it to return a different result when run twice.

Comment: Yes, but it should not differ by **10 seconds** ;-)

Comment: Accounting for file locking and write caching? I'd say it's possible.

Comment: it is not. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653686/php-on-windows-and-blocks/4653795#4653795