# PHP requests "queueing"

Tags: php, apache

I have the following problem: when executing very simple PHP scripts, e.g. this one:

```
<?php
echo "1";
sleep(10);
echo "2";
?>
```

and open it in multiple tabs *simultaneously*, the first tab finishes in 10 seconds, however the seconds waits 20 seconds instead of 10, so I'm guessing the requests are "queued" somehow.
Any ideas how to make them execute in parallel?

Configuration is as follows: LAMP stack, Ubuntu 10.10 64bit; Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l PHP/5.3.1 mod_apreq2-20090110/2.7.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1

I have added

```
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 0
MaxClients 512
MaxRequestsPerChild 100000
```

to httpd.conf, but besides that, it's the default httpd.conf that comes with lampp

Comment: either the tabs are screwing with you or your mis interpreting it, most sites have multiple visitors at once, imagine if this really was the case.

Comment: I realize that, however I think the problem is in my server configuration rather than the browser.

Comment: i don't know how to set up a sever to act in such a weird way, any out of the box are not going to act like that

Comment: I found out that this *could* be caused by session vars, however I have none, so it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: @KPetrov: what browser do you use? Try to request different urls with some rand added, like `?123`. So each tab has its own specific url.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653686/php-on-windows-and-blocks

Comment: zerkms, thanks, I used Chrome originally, now I tried Opera and it's working. I also added ?123 to as you suggested to change the URLs and Chrome worked, too. This appears to be some strange issue with caching for Chrome. Now I also noted several other scripts to be influenced by this URL thing. It appears the question is resolved. Thanks and sorry for the silly question

Comment: If you really want to start digging around, analyze your HTTP traffic either on your workstation or in the server logs.

Comment: Chrome was, it appears, checking if it needed to download it twice before attempting the 2nd download (and the third and so on) not really that bad an idea, but perhaps it should have made the decision once it saw the headers rather than waiting for the whole body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely its a browser issue. Some browsers have a limit on the number of multiple connections to the same server. Having queued connections with 2 tabs seems seems to low, so maybe its another reason but its worth checking out the advanced settings for your browsers.

Also, you may want to add output flushing after your echo functions and to output something which could give you more clues to whats happening - for example the server time.

Having a terminal window open and tailing the access log will also give you a better picture to whats happening.

Comment: Every tabed browser I've seen gives each tab a new connection pool - and you'd need to find a very old browser which had a limit of 2 concurrent connections

Comment: Actually it appears the issue is something close to that. When I changed the URLs, the connections were concurrent alright. I didn't investigate further, because in a real life situation my specific situation wouldn't happen. Original credit goes to zerkms, however zaf is the closest to the real answer.

Comment: @KPetrov Thanks. If you can upvote to remove the tight downvote then that would spread some optimism rather than the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
  // function for small sleeps that dont take cpu cycles
  function microdelay($delay) {
    $UNUSED_PORT = 31238; //make sure this port isn't being used on your server
    @fsockopen("tcp://localhost", $UNUSED_PORT, $errno, $errstr, $delay);
  }

  microdelay(.5); //500ms
  microdelay(.25); //250ms
  microdelay(2.25); //2250ms
```

Comment: Interesting - but why do you think that a sleep call on a Unix system should cost CPU cycles?

Comment: I'm quite sure that I've read about it somewhere, but for now, could not find the source and seems I'm mistaken. :/

Answer (score 0):

When you are using *sessions* a second request cannot start make use of it before the first one closes. Or you can use `session_write_close()` on the first one as soon as you don't make use of any session variables anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The parts of the http.conf you've provided suggest that you may reap some rewards by looking at this file in a bit more details (MaxKeepAliveRequests 0 - put a more sensible limit here).

In particular, do have a look at the number of servers you have running, e.g.

```
StartServers       5
MinSpareServers    2
MaxSpareServers    8
ServerLimit       64
```

This is a conservative setup for development work on a local workstation. For very low volume concurrent access, it might look something like....

```
 StartServers       8
 MinSpareServers    5
 MaxSpareServers   20
 ServerLimit      256
```